# Using VBA, loop through array of ranges and array of sheets to count occurrences of substring

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, count

So I’m trying to loop through an array of ranges in an array of sheets, and count the number of occurrences of a particular substring. Looping through the sheets and ranges is not a problem - I’ve done that many times, achieving the desired result, so I have the structure for that down pat.

My issue is that I can’t seem to find a way to count the number of times a particular substring (“Day 5”, for example) occurs within the ranges (each cell string starts with “Day (#)”). I’ve tried inside the innermost loop:

`subStrCount = subStrCount + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, subStr)`

where `Rng` is set to the desired range, inside a `For` loop, and `subStrCount` was set to 0, outside the loop. However, this returned a value of 0 when it executed. Any ideas?

Comment: `CountIf(Rng, subStr & "*")` but this would also count (eg) "Day 55" as well as "Day 5"

Comment: Showing the rest of your code would help.

Comment: @TimWilliams worked perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used array for finding the count of substring , it was working for me even if it is day1 or day12

```
Sub test1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = ws.Cells

substr = "day "
Dim daycount(20) As Long

For i = 1 To 15
    daycount(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, substr & i)
    Debug.Print daycount(i)
    Totalcount = Totalcount + daycount(i)
Next


End Sub
```